# Loop through and sum JSON values

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to loop through the below .json, extract the "total_price" field and sum it. I've tried recreating [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765929/using-reduce-to-loop-through-json)

However after much trial and error I just can't seem to grab the total__value field and sum it. Any help on what I need to do differently or how to alter the above solution for this scenario would be appreciated.

**JSON:**

```
"sales_mtd": {
"orders": [
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T16:30:47-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1099",
"total_price": "75.71"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T16:29:49-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1098",
"total_price": "47.46"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T16:29:27-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1097",
"total_price": "40.68"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T16:26:42-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1096",
"total_price": "29.69"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T16:23:41-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1095",
"total_price": "29.69"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T11:47:40-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1094",
"total_price": "29.69"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T11:46:14-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1093",
"total_price": "43.45"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T11:44:22-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1092",
"total_price": "43.45"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T00:41:59-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1091",
"total_price": "29.69"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T00:39:34-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1090",
"total_price": "67.95"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T00:36:18-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1089",
"total_price": "90.55"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T00:22:08-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1088",
"total_price": "43.45"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T00:14:16-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1087",
"total_price": "62.30"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T00:11:14-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1086",
"total_price": "43.45"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-25T00:03:49-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1085",
"total_price": "29.69"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-24T23:55:39-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1084",
"total_price": "66.82"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-24T23:52:07-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1083",
"total_price": "65.69"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-21T19:57:06-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
"name": "#MA-3097",
"total_price": "91.90"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-14T10:19:35-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1078",
"total_price": "48.74"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-12T00:06:22-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1077",
"total_price": "42.59"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-11T14:13:16-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1076",
"total_price": "52.29"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-10T23:06:49-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1075",
"total_price": "17.90"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-08T21:32:53-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1074",
"total_price": "55.52"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-02T15:20:33-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1072",
"total_price": "62.93"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-01T17:26:33-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1071",
"total_price": "48.60"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-06-01T16:19:55-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1069",
"total_price": "70.07"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-26T11:41:55-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1067",
"total_price": "62.16"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-25T18:58:44-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1066",
"total_price": "71.20"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-13T16:53:28-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1060",
"total_price": "42.59"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-13T09:46:59-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1057",
"total_price": "36.16"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-12T22:52:58-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1056",
"total_price": "85.87"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-10T18:29:43-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "69420",
"total_price": "42.94"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-06T12:32:48-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1054",
"total_price": "42.94"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-06T11:18:26-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1053",
"total_price": "221.48"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-05-04T21:56:52-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1052",
"total_price": "42.66"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-30T14:33:42-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1050",
"total_price": "80.17"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-30T14:31:05-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1049",
"total_price": "49.66"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-30T14:24:01-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1048",
"total_price": "51.92"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-27T12:31:34-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1047",
"total_price": "41.07"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-27T09:46:06-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1046",
"total_price": "70.57"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-21T09:57:23-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1044",
"total_price": "266.22"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-21T09:55:35-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1043",
"total_price": "202.29"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-21T09:54:20-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1042",
"total_price": "138.93"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-21T09:51:37-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1041",
"total_price": "48.53"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-14T13:12:48-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1040",
"total_price": "48.53"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-08T13:48:42-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1038",
"total_price": "48.53"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-04-06T09:30:17-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": "partial",
"name": "#1037",
"total_price": "109.61"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-03-27T07:10:25-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1035",
"total_price": "61.83"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-03-24T11:35:35-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1034",
"total_price": "72.44"
},
{
"created_at": "2021-03-19T11:55:19-04:00",
"fulfillment_status": null,
"name": "#1033",
"total_price": "59.57"
}
]
}
}
```

Here is code I tried using from above mentioned answer:

````
var sum = item.jobTasks.reduce(function(sum, elem) {
    return sum + (elem.cost && elem.cost.amountString ? elem.cost.amountString : 0) ;
}, 0);
console.log('jobNumber' + item.jobNumber + ' ' + sum);
});```
````

Comment: Please post your code on how you tried solving the problem

Comment: I had referenced the code in the top of the post but have since copied and pasted into the answer

Comment: You forgot to parse the JSON?

Comment: the sum of strings cannot give a numeric value ....

Comment: Where are you getting `cost` or `cost.amountString`? those aren't in the data structure

Answer (score 1):

Just get the orders `json.sales_mtd.orders` and loop through the orders, each time adding the `total_price` to the sum.

You can also do it with reduce, just return the sum of the current order and the previous orders as the new sum.

```js
let json = {
  "sales_mtd": {
    "orders": [{
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:30:47-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1099",
        "total_price": "75.71"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:29:49-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1098",
        "total_price": "47.46"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:29:27-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1097",
        "total_price": "40.68"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:26:42-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1096",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:23:41-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1095",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T11:47:40-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1094",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T11:46:14-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1093",
        "total_price": "43.45"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T11:44:22-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1092",
        "total_price": "43.45"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:41:59-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1091",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:39:34-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1090",
        "total_price": "67.95"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:36:18-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1089",
        "total_price": "90.55"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:22:08-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1088",
        "total_price": "43.45"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:14:16-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1087",
        "total_price": "62.30"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:11:14-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1086",
        "total_price": "43.45"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:03:49-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1085",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-24T23:55:39-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1084",
        "total_price": "66.82"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-24T23:52:07-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1083",
        "total_price": "65.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-21T19:57:06-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
        "name": "#MA-3097",
        "total_price": "91.90"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-14T10:19:35-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1078",
        "total_price": "48.74"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-12T00:06:22-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1077",
        "total_price": "42.59"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-11T14:13:16-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1076",
        "total_price": "52.29"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-10T23:06:49-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1075",
        "total_price": "17.90"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-08T21:32:53-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1074",
        "total_price": "55.52"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-02T15:20:33-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1072",
        "total_price": "62.93"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-01T17:26:33-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1071",
        "total_price": "48.60"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-01T16:19:55-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1069",
        "total_price": "70.07"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-26T11:41:55-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1067",
        "total_price": "62.16"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-25T18:58:44-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1066",
        "total_price": "71.20"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-13T16:53:28-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1060",
        "total_price": "42.59"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-13T09:46:59-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1057",
        "total_price": "36.16"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-12T22:52:58-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1056",
        "total_price": "85.87"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-10T18:29:43-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "69420",
        "total_price": "42.94"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-06T12:32:48-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1054",
        "total_price": "42.94"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-06T11:18:26-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1053",
        "total_price": "221.48"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-04T21:56:52-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1052",
        "total_price": "42.66"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-30T14:33:42-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1050",
        "total_price": "80.17"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-30T14:31:05-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1049",
        "total_price": "49.66"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-30T14:24:01-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1048",
        "total_price": "51.92"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-27T12:31:34-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1047",
        "total_price": "41.07"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-27T09:46:06-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1046",
        "total_price": "70.57"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T09:57:23-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1044",
        "total_price": "266.22"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T09:55:35-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1043",
        "total_price": "202.29"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T09:54:20-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1042",
        "total_price": "138.93"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T09:51:37-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1041",
        "total_price": "48.53"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-14T13:12:48-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1040",
        "total_price": "48.53"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:48:42-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1038",
        "total_price": "48.53"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-06T09:30:17-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": "partial",
        "name": "#1037",
        "total_price": "109.61"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-03-27T07:10:25-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1035",
        "total_price": "61.83"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-03-24T11:35:35-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1034",
        "total_price": "72.44"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-03-19T11:55:19-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1033",
        "total_price": "59.57"
      }
    ]
  }
};

let sumFor = 0;
for (let order of json.sales_mtd.orders) {
  sumFor += Number(order.total_price);
}

console.log(sumFor);

let sumReduce = json.sales_mtd.orders.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + Number(curr.total_price), 0);
console.log(sumReduce);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea why this was so hard. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Curious, why `new Number` rather than `Number`?

Comment: @EvanRobertson also added how to use reduce in this case

Comment: @Kinglish no particular reason, just a habit. You're right, we don't need it here :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a textbook example of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which takes 2 arguments, the accumulating value (b) and the item in the loop (a). You just need to convert the price into a number each iteration, which I did using the shorthand `+`

```
let sum = sales.sales_mtd.orders.reduce((b, a) => b + +a.total_price, 0).toFixed(2)
console.log(sum)
```

```js
const sales = {
  "sales_mtd": {
    "orders": [{
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:30:47-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1099",
        "total_price": "75.71"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:29:49-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1098",
        "total_price": "47.46"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:29:27-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1097",
        "total_price": "40.68"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:26:42-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1096",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T16:23:41-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1095",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T11:47:40-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1094",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T11:46:14-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1093",
        "total_price": "43.45"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T11:44:22-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1092",
        "total_price": "43.45"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:41:59-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1091",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:39:34-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1090",
        "total_price": "67.95"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:36:18-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1089",
        "total_price": "90.55"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:22:08-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1088",
        "total_price": "43.45"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:14:16-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1087",
        "total_price": "62.30"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:11:14-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1086",
        "total_price": "43.45"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-25T00:03:49-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1085",
        "total_price": "29.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-24T23:55:39-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1084",
        "total_price": "66.82"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-24T23:52:07-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1083",
        "total_price": "65.69"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-21T19:57:06-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
        "name": "#MA-3097",
        "total_price": "91.90"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-14T10:19:35-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1078",
        "total_price": "48.74"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-12T00:06:22-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1077",
        "total_price": "42.59"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-11T14:13:16-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1076",
        "total_price": "52.29"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-10T23:06:49-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1075",
        "total_price": "17.90"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-08T21:32:53-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1074",
        "total_price": "55.52"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-02T15:20:33-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1072",
        "total_price": "62.93"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-01T17:26:33-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1071",
        "total_price": "48.60"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-06-01T16:19:55-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1069",
        "total_price": "70.07"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-26T11:41:55-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1067",
        "total_price": "62.16"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-25T18:58:44-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1066",
        "total_price": "71.20"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-13T16:53:28-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1060",
        "total_price": "42.59"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-13T09:46:59-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1057",
        "total_price": "36.16"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-12T22:52:58-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1056",
        "total_price": "85.87"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-10T18:29:43-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "69420",
        "total_price": "42.94"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-06T12:32:48-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1054",
        "total_price": "42.94"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-06T11:18:26-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1053",
        "total_price": "221.48"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-05-04T21:56:52-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1052",
        "total_price": "42.66"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-30T14:33:42-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1050",
        "total_price": "80.17"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-30T14:31:05-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1049",
        "total_price": "49.66"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-30T14:24:01-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1048",
        "total_price": "51.92"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-27T12:31:34-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1047",
        "total_price": "41.07"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-27T09:46:06-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1046",
        "total_price": "70.57"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T09:57:23-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1044",
        "total_price": "266.22"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T09:55:35-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1043",
        "total_price": "202.29"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T09:54:20-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1042",
        "total_price": "138.93"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-21T09:51:37-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1041",
        "total_price": "48.53"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-14T13:12:48-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1040",
        "total_price": "48.53"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:48:42-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1038",
        "total_price": "48.53"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-04-06T09:30:17-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": "partial",
        "name": "#1037",
        "total_price": "109.61"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-03-27T07:10:25-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1035",
        "total_price": "61.83"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-03-24T11:35:35-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1034",
        "total_price": "72.44"
      },
      {
        "created_at": "2021-03-19T11:55:19-04:00",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "name": "#1033",
        "total_price": "59.57"
      }
    ]
  }
}

let sum = sales.sales_mtd.orders.reduce((b, a) => b + +a.total_price, 0).toFixed(2)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you, tried to reduce method and screwed it up each time, appreciate it!